# Is there a search component for amp-story?

Tags: search, amp-html, amp-story

- How are searches done in amp-story?
- What are the different options for integrating search into amp-story?
- What are the pros and cons of each option?

**references**

- https://www.ampproject.org/stories
- https://ampbyexample.com/stories/introduction/amp_story_hello_world/
- https://ampbyexample.com/stories/#stories/features

Comment: What would you be searching over?  Stories are not replacements for a standard site navigation structure, but rather pieces of content.

Comment: I mean to embed a search box into a page.  Many websites today have search boxes on the home page.  The search boxes can help you navigate the site. The box can also provide a list of answers to a question about a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms and input fields are currently not supported by amp-story.  The full list of supported elements can be found by looking at the documentation for the type of layer you are using.  For example, see the [list of supported descendents of `amp-story-grid-layer`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#children].

Comment: Input fields seem to be a pretty common request for websites. Are there no plans to add input fields or forms to amp-story? Is current best practice to link to a non amp-story page that has an input field or form?

Comment: AMP stories are not intended to be a replacement for normal webpages.  They are a different medium with a different purpose and different constraints.  That said, you can always [file a feature request](http://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) for AMP to support this.

Comment: None of this is mentioned in the documentation. When offering a new product, I would say that it is important to say what service you provide and what services you do not intend to provide. It isn't clear from the documentation that basic functionality of websites will not be available.

Moreover, if you are integrating amp-access and payment solutions into amp-stories(via amp-paywall), it seems that simple search functionality should have been prioritised equally.